# Update only one package with pacman

Tags: package-management, arch-linux, pacman

Is there a way to update only selected programs in pacman?

I'm running ArchLinux on my netbook, and the complete upgrade of my system takes up more temporary space than I have on my system, so I'd like to just update one program at a time

Comment: This will cause breakage at some point. You are better of upgrading everything (it is a rolling release), and then every couple of days or weeks backing up /var/cache/pacman to an external drive and flushing the cache with pacman -Scc

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Pacman's install command really means 'synchronize', so the command to install a new package and to upgrade a single package is the same.

```
pacman -S packagename
```

This will upgrade the package.

Comment: A `package -Syu` might be necessary before, so you actually have a relevant version to synchronize with. See [the doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Upgrading_packages)

Comment: isn't this considered a "partial upgrade" and therefore unsupported/not recommended?

Comment: ah I guess only if you do a `pacman -Sy` before, then you'd run into danger of breaking packages

Answer (score 13):

In pacman, you can actually specify the `cache` directory:

```
--cachedir <dir> set an alternate package cache location
```

So if you plug a USB stick into your computer, you can do a full system upgrade the normal way and just toss the downloaded packages onto the stick, like so:

```
pacman -Syu --cache /media/USB_STICK/pacman/
```

It doesn't take much space (a normal `1GB` stick will suffice), so it should work fine with your netbook.

If you have slow internet, you can even create a download list and download the files from another computer, like so:

```
pacman -Syup
```

And it will print out a list of package URLs. Quite useful (at least to me).